# Mechanism of electron delocalisation from the other end of alicyclic chain

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

When one adds $\ce{Br2}$ and $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ to 5-Methylhex-5-enol, this mechanism follows;
[image]

Also,in adding $\ce{Br2}$ to 2,2-Dimethylhexa-3,4-dienol, this follows;
[image]

What is the mechanism here, in which the electrons from a hydroxyl on the other side of the C-chain is delocalised to the other side?

Comment: I guess you could call it an intramolecular cyclisation

Comment: Is there anything particular about the OH group?

Comment: I am not aware of some significant naming regarding that